# gdbserver as an inetdamon broken pipe

Tags: gdb, inetd

Ive added gdbserver in the inetd.conf and etc/services yet when I attempt to connect as follows I immediately get Remote communication error. Target disconnected.: Broken pipe.

(gdb) target extended-remote rtx5:8010
Remote debugging using rtx5:8010
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Broken pipe.

8010 is what I have configured gdbserver to run on. However if I manually start gdbserver from the target with 8011 I can get them communicating.

I tried adding "--multi" and the port to the inetd.conf file and reloaded it to no avail.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by doing the following:

In inetd.conf "gdbserver --multi -" Using the dash apparently directs the server to use stdin and out.

I am interested to know why exactly this works.